# Gmail bouncing my mails from my VM

Tags: smtp, gmail, postfix-mta

I must admit I am a mail server noob. However today when trying to send mail to a gmail address from my VM (for development reasons) using Postfix I got:

```
Apr  7 15:44:17 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1792]: 3061D40A0C: to=<xxx@googlemail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.66.26]:25, delay=0.95, delays=0.02/0/0.38/0.54, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.66.26] said: 550-5.7.1 [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at 550 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=10336 bl2si5263213wib.27 (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

I have x'd out the email address and my IP so I ain't showing potentially sensitive info however with that aside I have been reading around that I need to add a certain IP or SMTP server however I cannot seem to get a clear answer from searching around.

So I am wondering how can I make Gmail allow my VMed personal server (sitting on my computer) send mails to my Gmail account?

Is there a document about explaining how to properly set up the sender in Postfix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember trying to do exactly the same thing a while back because I wanted Nagios xi email notifications.
The URL in that error is clear enough: if the domain you set in your email "from" field does not match the domain name that your VM mailserver IP resolves to then google will not accept the mail.
What you need to do is find out the smtp server for your ISP and set that as the mail relay.

You may also find that some ISPs block the default smtp port (usually port 25) in an outbound direction (so you can receive mail but cannot send). Looks like it's not blocked in general on your connection but it may be blocked to the ISPs mailserver and so you'd want to make sure that such traffic is permitted.

Alternatively, I found that hotmail worked well enough without jumping through hoops.

Comment: Whoop, I changed my from field to match my postfix domain and I able to spoof Gmail into recieving my mails without having to put a relay on, thanks for the answer mate!